# Download link to osm2pgsql

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I need to download the osm2pgsql for Windows

i tried from the path which is given in wiki

http://customdebug.com/osm/osm2pgsql.zip

and also from below link

http://tile.openstreetmap.org/osm2pgsql.zip

Both are not working

Please share me if any one has this for Windows 64Bit

Comment: Did you try GitHub? Look here: https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql

Comment: Thanks Map..in github only code is present.. i need the tool to run in windows

Comment: I did not test it but how about this link: https://vanguard.houghtonassociates.com/browse/OSM-OSM2PSQL-43/artifact

Comment: If you get stuck finding a live link with a recent installer, you could try OSMOSIS as an alternative.

Comment: that is better.. i will do that..

Comment: @MappaGnosis Osmosis does not populate the database in the way Mapnik expects it.

Comment: True - but that's a specific use-case.  The OP didn't specify Mapnik so maybe Osmosis can provide a solution.

Comment: can we get an update on the 64 bit version? the hot_installer does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this link: https://github.com/springmeyer/win-osm-workshop/blob/master/Tutorial.md#step-7-install-osm2pgsql osm2pgsql is included in the HOT-installer: https://github.com/hotosm/installer/downloads. However, the last update is from 2010 but maybe it fits your needs.

Comment: You will not get lucky with old versions of osm2pgsql becausse they can not read 64 bit integer node numbers. Since OSM has hit this line some time ago, every imort with older versions will fail at some stage.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I am still using the May 2013 build of Dominik Perpeet from http://www.customdebug.com/osm2pgsql/ but the server is currently down.

---

You can follow the latest development of the Windows build at

https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/17

The issue features three different versions, two from onepromise via vanguard.houghtonassociates.com and one from alex85k via dropbox

The first source offers mingw and cygwin builds, which can be found under
[OSM-MINGW64OSM2PGSQL](https://vanguard.houghtonassociates.com/browse/OSM-MINGW64OSM2PGSQL) and [OSM-OSM2PSQL](https://vanguard.houghtonassociates.com/browse/OSM-OSM2PSQL)
Current latest builds are #38 for mingw and #95 for cygwin. Downloads are available if you click on the build Number (if it is green), then the in the `Artifact` tab

The **mingw** version depends on some dlls from mingw64: `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll` and `libwinpthread-1.dll` which are not included. mingw64 is avaliable from http://win-builds.org/download.html using the package manager.

Unfortuantely, the mingw version does not work for me because it cannot connect to the postgreSQL server (which works with all other versions osm2pgsql and QGIS).

---

The **cygwin** version needs `-H localhost` added to the command line to run, but the cache size is limited to `--cache 2000`. This is less than the old build can work with.

---

The version from **alex85k** is built with MS VC++ compiler and supposed to be faster. The latest build from 26.10.2014 works for me, no tweaks on the command line necessary.

The build from 15.Sep does not work.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware a few dependencies were missing. I can easily add libgcc_s_seh-1.dll and libwinpthread-1.dll into the build archive. Otherwise, you can always retrieve them from https://vanguard.houghtonassociates.com/browse/MINGLE-MINGLE64-203/artifact

Comment: Well, downloading 833MB is not a good alternative for just two small missing files. I had not found the files in the light zip version. But the connection error prevented me from using it anyway, and the cache limit for the cygwin version.

Answer (score 2):

The latest osm2pgsql Windows builds (June/2018):

x86: https://ci.appveyor.com/api/projects/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/artifacts/osm2pgsql_Release_x86.zip?job=Environment%3A%20arch%3Dx86

x64: https://ci.appveyor.com/api/projects/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/artifacts/osm2pgsql_Release_x64.zip?job=Environment%3A%20arch%3Dx64

Comment: I've downloaded it but can't run it? How to install it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the installer for Windows here - https://ci.appveyor.com/project/alex85k/osm2pgsql/build/artifacts - the latest version is from 2017. It works with Postgres 10.3 on Windows 10, for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use GDAL OGR2OGR to convert your OSM Data (PBF or OSM XML file) into POSTGIS or anyother supported OGR format. You can also do queries with OGRINFO or SELECT what data to convert in your OGR2OGR -sql "SELECT column names FROM osm WHERE statement"  http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html
http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html