# Where to find Windows osm2psql binaries in 2018?

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I've read all the stuff in their git, here at stackexchange, in OSM wiki, but all links are broken and the latest windows binary I found is HOTOSM bundle built at 2010.

- [Download link to osm2pgsql](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118334/download-link-to-osm2pgsql)
- https://ci.appveyor.com/project/alex85k/osm2pgsql
  all are dead.

It seems so strange for me, I even thought that people use another software to load OSM data to PostgreSQL for to use as GeoServer datasource. But OSM wiki mainly mention this program.

I surely do not know what to do now, I need the 
Windows distribution of it OR another simple way to load and show OSM data via GeoServer pgsql datasource.

Where can I find Windows osm2psql binaries in 2018?

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/888

Comment: I've read it but didn't figure out the way to find the binaries, although they were at their place:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [README](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/README.md):

> Unoffical builds for Windows are available from AppVeyor but you need to find the right build artifacts.

However, the the links in the README to builds of the latest release 0.96.0 are broken as the artifacts [are no longer available](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/888#issuecomment-446594654):

> Artifacts older than 6 months are automatically deleted. For more details see Artifacts retention policy.

To find a build:

- Go to the [build history](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/history)
- Find the most recent build that hasn't failed (i.e. 
  "*[Merge pull request #891 from lonvia/back-to-copymode 0.0.641](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/builds/21049230)*"
- Select 32 or 64bit (i.e. [Environment: arch=x64](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/builds/21049230/job/hct9b9st9lif9qkm))
- Download the [artifact](https://ci.appveyor.com/api/buildjobs/hct9b9st9lif9qkm/artifacts/osm2pgsql_Release_x64.zip) (osm2pgsql_Release_x64.zip).

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO much! I somehow didn't figure out how to find build artifacts on AppVeyour, so sorry for the stupidity%)